# iOS Build to Device Not Working when Deployment Target is below iOS 13.0

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, ios13

### Background:

Everything worked fine a few days ago... I was able to build to device apps with a deployment target of **10.3**. Today, they will only build to devices when the deployment target is set to **13.0+**. There is zero issues when building to the simulator. I did not perform any update to my OS or XCode prior.

### Build Errors:

```
error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
error: Failed with exit code 1
```

It's throwing these errors on some of the swift libraries.

### What I've tried so far:

- Did the whole close Xcode, delete Derived Folder, Open Xcode, Clean Build, Build
- Revoked and issued new Certificates via Apple Developer Portal and removed old ones
- Moved the keys to System in keychain
- Uninstalled and reinstalled XCode (was running 11.3.1 and currently running 11.3.1)

### What to do next?

I haven't had much luck in my research of more things to try other than I read someone had to reinstall their OS... I really don't want to have to do that...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Magically, this was solved when I was able to update to Catalina...

Answer (score -1):

The only option is to reinstall your OS as keychain problems are solved by reinstalling the OS. As once i forgot my keychain password and when i recover it back it was showing problems in making builds so i have to reinstall my OS.